# Adding an image to a PDF using iTextSharp and scale it properly

Tags: c#, image, itext

here's my code. It correctly adds the pictures I want and everything works **except** that the images are using their native resolution, so if the image is big it's being cropped to fit the page.

Is there some way to have the picture use like a Zoom feature to stretch to fit, but also maintain the aspect ratio? There has to be something I'm missing there. :P

Here's a picture to illustrate the problem:
[image]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WinformsPlayground
{
    public class PDFWrapper
    {
        public void CreatePDF(List<System.Drawing.Image> images)
        {
            if (images.Count >= 1)
            {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
                try
                {

                    // step 2:
                    // we create a writer that listens to the document
                    // and directs a PDF-stream to a file

                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("Chap0101.pdf", FileMode.Create));

                    // step 3: we open the document
                    document.Open();

                    foreach (var image in images)
                    {
                        iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        document.Add(pic);
                        document.NewPage();
                    }
                }
                catch (DocumentException de)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
                }

                // step 5: we close the document
                document.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

I solved it using the following:

```
foreach (var image in images)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    if (pic.Height > pic.Width)
    {
        //Maximum height is 800 pixels.
        float percentage = 0.0f;
        percentage = 700 / pic.Height;
        pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
    }
    else
    {
        //Maximum width is 600 pixels.
        float percentage = 0.0f;
        percentage = 540 / pic.Width;
        pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
    }

    pic.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
    pic.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK;
    pic.BorderWidth = 3f;
    document.Add(pic);
    document.NewPage();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Personally, I use something close from fubo's solution and it works well:

```
image.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize);
image.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0);
```

Comment: wORKED FOR ME, except that I changed image.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize);
to image.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize.Width,document.PageSize.Height);

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this:

```
      Image logo = Image.GetInstance("pathToTheImage")
      logo.ScaleAbsolute(500, 300)
```

Comment: So, in your case it will be: pic.ScaleAbsolute(width, height);

Comment: This method is no use because it's scales it absolute. It stretches the image and distorts it. I need a way to have it get bigger while maintaining aspect ratio and keeping within the document.

Comment: Here is an article about the image resolution in iTextSharp. I haven't used it. But you can try. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

Comment: article posted by @Hps helped me

Answer (score 5):

```
image.ScaleToFit(500f,30f);
```

this method keeps the aspect ratio of the image

Answer (score 1):

```
image.SetAbsolutePosition(1,1);
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Setting only the position merely shifts the visible section of the image, it does not implicitly scale it.

Answer (score 0):

As iTextSharp is EOL, and has been replaced by iText 7.
The answers above are correct, but a little bit out of date.
There is some solution for iText 7:

```
// Adding usings for image creation
using iText.IO.Image;
using iText.Layout.Element;

// Adding usings for document creation
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Pdfa;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

// Creating a PDF
//fileName is the name of the future PDF file
//filePath is the path where PDF file will be saved
PdfADocument pdf = new PdfADocument(
    new PdfWriter(fileName),
    PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B,
    new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1",
    new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)));

//Creating a PDF document
var doc = new Document(pdf);

// Creating an ImageData object
// imageFilePath is a path to yours image file         
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(imageFilePath);              
  
// Creating an Image object        
Image image = new Image(imageData);                        
  
// Adding image to the document       
doc.Add(image);
```