# How to add image file in pdf using itext in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

how to add image file with itextSharp in asp.net C#. And which namespace is required

```
Image jpg** = Image.GetInstance(new Uri(URL))
```

Comment: For this purpose there is a documentation...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325151/adding-an-image-to-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-and-scale-it-properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iTextSharp.text.Image` for adding images. Something like this:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
myDocument.Add(pic);
```

Where **myDocument** is the object of `Document` Class of itextsharp

Here if one details article which discuss handling images in itextsharp

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

and may be you might be interested in going through documentation also, so here is the link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

using(Stream ImageStream = new FileStream(imageUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))

Image image = Image.GetInstance(ImageStream);