# Image getting printed with low resolution

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have a requirement to create pdf with images for printing. I am adding a high  resolution image to pdf using iText. It's reducing the quality to 72 DPI.
Resulting in poor quality of image after printing.

The original image resolution is 2549*3304 and DPI (300).

I tried  below options

```
image.scaleAbsolute(2549*.24 ,3304*.24 ); 

image.setDpi(300,300);     

image.scaleToFit(2549*.24 ,3304*.24 );
```

current code looks like this

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

document.open();

Image image = Image.getInstance("C:/Project/bg.png");

image.setAbsolutePosition(0,0);

image.scalePercent(24);

document.add(image);

document.close();
```

I went through some threads ([Adding an image to a PDF using iTextSharp and scale it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325151/adding-an-image-to-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-and-scale-it-properly)) still not able to solve the problem

Can anyone please help me on this to get better image quality while printing?

Comment: What does your code look now?

Comment: Why are you scaling? Your image is 8.5" by 11" at 300dpi. Then you throw away 76% of your image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setDpi()` method is irrelevant in your code, so is the DPI of your original image. Pixels are treated as points in iText. This means that adding an image as-is will result in having 72 pixels per inch.

You scale the image to 24 percent of the original size. This means that you increase the resolution: you are showing the same number of pixels using only 24% of the space. In this case, you are showing 2549 pixels distributed over 611.76 points. This is about 8.5 inch, which means you indeed have a resolution of 300 DPI.

I think the problem isn't caused by the resolution of the image inside the PDF (but it's hard to tell because we can't inspect the PDF). I think the problem is caused by the printing process that prints the document using a resolution that is different from the resolution in the PDF.

In any case: iText does not reduce the number of pixels if you use the methods `scalePercent()`, `scaleAbsolute()` or `scaleToFit()`.

**Extra info based on Comments:**

Asking a PDF for its "resolution" doesn't make sense, because a PDF doesn't have any resolution (although images inside a PDF may have one). I have no idea why Photoshop tells you the resolution is 72 DPI. Maybe that's a default value because the measurment unit in PDF corresponds with a point and there are 72 points in one inch.

I have examined the PDF that you shared. I don't see any loss of resolution when I look at it on my screen. I can see that the document measures 8.5 by 11 inch. As for the image, please take a look at the report generated by Acrobat:

[image]

It says width/height: 2550/3300 in pixel.

2550 / 8.5 = 300

3300 / 11 = 300

Hence the resolution is 300 pixels per inch. Or: the PDF is created exactly the way you want it.

However: you say that the resolution is worse when you print the document. This can be caused by many different things: maybe you're printing on a page that is larger than 8.5 by 11 inch, maybe the printer can't print at that resolution, maybe the PDF viewer can only print using "degraded printing",...

My advice is that you test this PDF on different printers using different viewers to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for the quick reply.For comparison I printed the original PNG image and generated pdf. The quality of pdf print out is not good compared to that of PNG print out. Also when I open the pdf in photoshop it shows the DPI as 72. SO its confusing me

Comment: Can you share the PDF? Because it also confuses me. When you say that PhotoShop tells your the DPI is 72, I assume that PhotoShop gives you the DPI of the embedded image, not the DPI of the image as it is rendered in the PDF (PDF as such doesn't have a resolution).

Comment: I have uploaded both the image and pdf @ https://www.dropbox.com/sh/idtlde2q39noqth/AADt8EJMoxpdJR4gBLzmAl7ua

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. It feels great when you the get the answers from the creator