# while exporting html to pdf image is not displaying in itextsharp pdf document in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

i want to add company logo on the top using img control. but while downloading image in pdf it is not displaying. while giving remote url link for image its displaying , but while giving server path of folders its not displaying image

```
 <table style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid;width:666px" align="center">


      <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
            <td style="border: 1px solid;width:50%" colspan="2">

              <img src="img/kst.png" />
             </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid;width:50%" colspan="2">Hyderabad, India</td>
            <br />
            <br />
        </tr>
```

code behind

```
string Projname = "Payslip";
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}.pdf\"", Projname));
                // Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=WeeklyReport.pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
                design.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

                string myText = stringWrite.ToString();
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(myText.ToString());
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                Response.End();
                pdfDoc.Dispose();
                design.Visible = false;
```

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325151/adding-an-image-to-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-and-scale-it-properly

Comment: i want to add image at particular location where i have image control.

Comment: have you tried with absolute url?

Comment: NO I HAVE NOT TRIED WITH ABOLUTE URL . HOW CAN WE WRITE

Comment: instead of src="img/kst.png" try something like src="http://yourdomain.com/img/kst.png"

Comment: im hosting in local . and that machine dont have internet. can i use private ip ?

Comment: then try giving localhost for domain.make sure the path is absolute

Comment: ok thanks. i think this idea will work out for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute url as image source for `src="img/kst.png"` try something like `src="http://yourdomain.com/img/kst.png"`

Answer (score 2):

I Use this:

```
<img src="@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/????.???")" />
```

It works for me.

And you haven't to changed the PATH if you release the project