# Images generated by itextsharp 5 shows in pdf file larger than original

Tags: c#, image, itext, pdf-generation

I am trying to add image to PDF document.
Image size is 145x53px.

But image looks bigger in PDF document.

How to fix the issue?
I need that picture will be displayed as normal size.

Code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream( "C:\\Temp\\First PDF document.pdf", FileMode.Create);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 25, 30, 30);  
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);

document.Open();
        
// Add an image
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\\Temp\\Img\\test.png");
document.Add(img);
document.Add(new Paragraph("Original Width: " + img.Width.ToString()));
document.Add(new Paragraph("Original Height " + img.Height.ToString()));
document.Add(new Paragraph("Scaled Width: " + img.ScaledWidth.ToString()));
document.Add(new Paragraph("Scaled Height " + img.ScaledHeight.ToString()));

document.Close();
writer.Close();
```

PNG:

[image]

PDF:

[image]

Comment: Hi, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325151/adding-an-image-to-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-and-scale-it-properly) help? On of the scaling method calls seems to be needed, to scale your image relative to your documents size.

Comment: Hi @nilsK I tried to scale it but no luck. Tried img.ScaleAbsolute(145f, 53f); and img.ScaleToFit(145f, 53f);

Comment: PDF expects you to use dpi not pixels.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. PDF is vectorized, it's not bitmapped. I could tell you to just zoom out until it looks right.

Comment: How to set size in dpi? @TaW

Comment: img.SetResolution(...)

Comment: The units used by iText usually are points, pt, 1/72in; px on the other hand usually are seen as 1/96in. You have to scale accordingly.

Comment: When I do scaling, for examlple - img.ScalePercent(75f) - Quality of on image degraded. How to prevent it @mkl

Comment: *"When I do scaling, for examlple - img.ScalePercent(75f) - Quality of on image degraded. How to prevent it"* - That should not happen because iText does _not_ scale down the bitmap itself, it merely arranges the current transformation matrix at the time of image drawing so that the PDF viewer knows the desired size. Please share a PDF illustrating the quality loss.